# Split row string into columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have `conversion` column in some table which contains next strings:

```
9076635012/DOVE/603524/source:unilever/campaign:L-Unilever_Tresemme_SMM_jan-feb2021/content:video_18_Stories/medium:display
707663501/AXE/60364/source:unilever/campaign:AXE/term:instagram/medium:display
```

I want to get next result:

| id | brand | code | source | campaign | content | term | medium |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9076635012 | DOVE | 603524 | unilever | L-Unilever_Tresemme_SMM_jan-feb2021 | video_18_Stories | NULL | display |
| 707663501 | AXE | 60364 | unilever | AXE | NULL | instagram | display |

I can easily split `id, brand, code`:

```
SELECT
split_part(a."conversion", '/', 1)  as id,
split_part(a."conversion", '/', 2) as brand,
split_part(a."conversion", '/', 3) as code
```

How to split next parts? Pattern is `/attribute_name:` like `/content:` and consider that one of the part may not exist in 1st row, but can exist in 2nd row. And if it's possible
it doesn't have to be order-oriented. `campaign` can be at the begining (right after `code`) or at the end.   `id, brand, code` always exist and always have same order.

I tried like this:

```
substring(split_part(a."conversion", '/source:', 2),'[^\/]') as source
```

But get `u` as source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regexp version of `substring` and anchor words in order to be position independent. Here is an illustration with a CTE.

```sql
with t(conversation) as
(
 values 
 ('9076635012/DOVE/603524/source:unilever/campaign:L-Unilever_Tresemme_SMM_jan-feb2021/content:video_18_Stories/medium:display'), 
 ('707663501/AXE/60364/source:unilever/campaign:AXE/term:instagram/medium:display')
)
select 
    split_part(conversation, '/', 1)  as id,
    split_part(conversation, '/', 2)  as brand,
    split_part(conversation, '/', 3)  as code,
    substring(conversation from '/source:([^/]+)/?')   as source,   
    substring(conversation from '/campaign:([^/]+)/?') as campaign,   
    substring(conversation from '/content:([^/]+)/?')  as "content",   
    substring(conversation from '/term:([^/]+)/?')     as term,   
    substring(conversation from '/medium:([^/]+)/?')   as medium   
from t;

/* Result:
id        |brand|code  |source  |campaign                           |content         |term     |medium |
----------+-----+------+--------+-----------------------------------+----------------+---------+-------+
9076635012|DOVE |603524|unilever|L-Unilever_Tresemme_SMM_jan-feb2021|video_18_Stories|         |display|
707663501 |AXE  |60364 |unilever|AXE                                |                |instagram|display|
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Just split again:

```
SELECT split_part(a."conversion", '/', 1)  as id,
       split_part(a."conversion", '/', 2) as brand,
       split_part(a."conversion", '/', 3) as code,
       split_part(split_part(a."conversion", '/', 4), ':', 1) as source,
       . . .
```

Comment: What about ordering? F.e. `source` can be at `4` position in one string, and at `6` position in second string. Can I handle this case?

Comment: @hsadik . . . I don't see that in your question.